# How to do GREPL 'OR' statements with an 'AND' in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use GREPL to search words in a dataframe. I am trying to do something with an 'OR' function but also with 'AND's and I do not think I am doing the right order.  For example,

```
if(grepl("green|red|orange|Pink & Blue|yellow", df$A,ignore.case = True), "Color")
```

but a lot more words. How do I use the & in the OR statement? I keep geting that the comma is unexpected.

Comment: Pink & Blue is a string to be matched ? Could you give example of how `df$A` looks like ?

Comment: There's no direct way to use a logical AND in a regex. You either have to use two calls to `grepl` and connect them with `&` or do something like `(A.*B)|(B.*A)` if you're looking for a string that contains `A` and `B` in any order.

Comment: `grepl` returns a vector having the same length as `df` has rows. If df has more than 2 rows, you shouldn't use `if`, but an `ifelse`.  The `,` has no meaning inside an `if`

Comment: Yes. The column "A" in df is sentences. Such as "The little girl said her favorite color was blue". Maybe the color example does not make too much sense with the "Pink & Blue", but I am trying to classify insurance claims into weather/non-weather. For example, "Golf Ball" would be non-weather, but "Golf Ball"  & "Hail" would be weather. I am trying to make a giant "OR" statement of weather words.

Comment: @Reagan in that case it doesn't sound like you need `&` at all?

Comment: @user5783745 I need the 'AND' because the combination of "Golf-Ball" and "Hail"  would make a difference in the classification of the claim.

Comment: is it "(pink & blue)" or any of the others, or "(green/red/orange/pink) AND (blue/yellow)"?

Comment: but why does the "golf ball" part matter at all? If there's "hail", it's weather related.

Comment: It would be (pink & blue) OR any others. Perhaps I used a bad example with the hail, another example could be "Tree" and "Fell" which is may be weather related and "Tree" and "Dead" which is not weather related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(grepl("green|red|orange|Pink", df$A, ignore.case=T) 
  & grepl("Blue|yellow", df$A, ignore.case=T) {"Color"}
```

As noted by @R.Schifini above, if doesn't work like that. That's the issue with the comma. The curly brackets aren't strictly necessary, they're just here to clarify the syntax in this case.

If it's just the pair of pink and blue that need to be joined by and, this should work:

```
if(grepl("green|red|orange|yellow", df$A, ignore.case=T) 
  | (grepl("Blue", df$A, ignore.case=T) & grepl("pink", df$A, ignore.case=T))) {"Color"}
```

This will only work for a single string. If you want to vectorize it, you can use ifelse, or do something like this:

```
colcheck<-function(x) {if(grepl("green|red|orange|yellow", x, ignore.case=T) 
    | (grepl("Blue", x, ignore.case=T) & grepl("pink", x, ignore.case=T))) "Color" else NA}

sapply(df$A, colcheck)
```

Comment: Can I add another and statement after that? I have a couple of them that need to be joined, but I tried this method with all of them and I am getting an error.

Comment: sorry, was missing a close parenthesis there. Note this will only work if df$A has only one string. Otherwise you'll need to either use ifelse, or sapply.

Comment: added another solution that can be used over a vector.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you're after:

```
claims <- c("golf ball hit car", "hail caused damage", "the little girl liked to read", "a branch broke ou verandah")
df <- data.frame(claims, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

accident <- c("hit", "break", "crash", "fell", "broke")
weather <- c("storm", "lightning", "hail")


df$accident <- ifelse(grepl(paste(accident, collapse="|"), df$claims, ignore.case = TRUE), "Yes", "No")
df$weather <- ifelse(grepl(paste(weather, collapse="|"), df$claims, ignore.case = TRUE), "Yes", "No")
df
```

If you wanted to, you could always replace `paste(weather, collapse="|")` with `"storm | lightning | hail"` (although the readability of your code may suffer if the list of terms is long)

Comment: I think I understand this code. I believe that what I am trying to do with the code originally posted is to create the "accident" and "weather" dataframes by picking out words from a column in another dataframe. The original data is just like your claim data. I am confused though how grepl would help separate weather words from the original data to without the "accident" and "weather" columns.